# Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{S}^n$ in practice

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I want to compute $\int_{\mathbb{S}^n} f(y) d\mu (y)$ with $n=2$, $f$ defined on $\mathbb{S}^n$, and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{S}^n$.

How do I evaluate this? Do I just replace $d\mu (y)$ with $\sin(\phi)d\phi d\theta$ after switching to spherical coordinates like with a normal surface integral?

Any help is appreciated! I've only worked with Lebesgue measure theoretically so far.

Comment: What definition of Lebesgue measure are you working with? I believe you'd need some additionaly information regarding your function $f$. And by $\Bbb{S}^2$ I take it you are referring to the unit $2-$sphere?

Comment: Lot of examples use Stoke's theorem for computation, it is a differential geometry result, a generalization of integration by parts if you wish but if you function is only defined on $\mathbb{S}^n$ you better use a parametrization ;) as you suggested, but calculations are very complicated

Comment: Should the title not just mention $\mathbb S^2\,?$ We know that in spherical coordinates we calculate integrals of functions definied on the surface by $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}f(\phi,\theta)\sin\phi\,d\phi\,d\theta\,.$ So take the Lebesgue measure on $[0,\pi)\times[0,2\pi)$ and you are done.